# How do you export objects with a varying amount of properties?

Tags: powershell

Warning - I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483674/method-to-export-objects-with-varying-properties) in the past but this is slightly different.

tl;dr; I want to export objects which have a varying number of properties. eg; object 1 may have 3 IP address and 2 NICs but object 2 has 7 IP addresses and 4 NICs (but not limited to this amount - it could be N properties).

I can happily capture and build objects that contain all the information I require. If I simply output my array to the console each object is shown with all its properties. If I want to out-file or export-csv I start hitting a problem surrounding the headings.

Previously [JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc) recommended sorting the objects based on the amount of properties - ie, the object with the most properties would come first and hence the headings for the most amount of properties would be output.

Say I have built an object of servers which has varying properties based on IP addresses and NIC cards. For example;

```
ServerName: Mordor
IP1: 10.0.0.1
IP2: 10.0.0.2
NIC1: VMXNET
NIC2: Broadcom

ServerName: Rivendell
IP1: 10.1.1.1
IP2: 10.1.1.2
IP3: 10.1.1.3
IP4: 10.1.1.4
NIC1: VMXNET
```

Initially, if you were to export-csv an array of these objects the headers would be built upon the first object (aka, you would only get ServerName, IP1, IP2, NIC1 and NIC2) meaning for the second object you would lose any subsequent IPs (eg IP3 and IP4). To correct this, before an export I sort based on the number of IP properties - tada - the first object now has the most IPs in the array and hence none of the subsequent objects IPs are lost.

The downside is when you then have a second varying property - eg NICs. Once my sort is complete based on IP we then have the headings ServerName, IP1 - IP4 and NIC1. This means the subsequent object property of NIC2 is lost.

Is there a scalable way to ensure that you aren't losing data when exporting objects like this?

Comment: I was lucky enough to speak with Jeffrey Snover who confirmed Export-Csv can't work in this scenario. Jeffrey's advice was to shift toward Export-CliXML and build a report on this output. Sigh.

Comment: Have you tried my update answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$o1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
ServerName="Mordor"
IP1="10.0.0.1"
IP2="10.0.0.2"
NIC1="VMXNET"
NIC2="Broadcom"
}

$o2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
ServerName="Rivendell"
IP1="10.1.1.1"
IP2="10.1.1.2"
IP3="10.1.1.3"
IP4="10.1.1.4"
NIC1="VMXNET"
}

$arr = @()
$arr += $o1
$arr += $o2

#Creating output
$prop = $arr | % { Get-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name } | Select -Unique | Sort-Object
$headers = @("ServerName")
$headers += $prop -notlike "ServerName"

$arr | ft -Property $headers
```

Output:

```
ServerName IP1      IP2      IP3      IP4      NIC1   NIC2    
---------- ---      ---      ---      ---      ----   ----    
Mordor     10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2                   VMXNET Broadcom
Rivendell  10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3 10.1.1.4 VMXNET
```

If you know the types(NICS, IPS..), but not the count(ex. how many NICS) you could try:

```
#Creating output
$headers = $arr | % { Get-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name } | Select -Unique
$ipcount = ($headers -like "IP*").Count
$niccount = ($headers -like "NIC*").Count

$format = @("ServerName")
for ($i = 1; $i -le $ipcount; $i++) { $format += "IP$i" }
for ($i = 1; $i -le $niccount; $i++) { $format += "NIC$i" }

$arr | ft -Property $format
```

Comment: Sadly, the aim is to get an easy to read report so list format isn't ideal.

Comment: Fixed it as much as I could now. More manipulation would require select, cut and paste in excel I think :) The first method sorts properties alphabetical and adds servername as first column. The second is if you know all the types of properties(in this case IP* and NIC*)

Comment: This looks good - to get to export-csv I've changed your ft to a simple `select $headers`. I much prefer your first method as I prefer something modular that doesn't require me to know all the properties etc. Thanks! Testing in a second scenario now.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting a list of all unique property headers and then doing a select on all the objects? When you do a select on an object for a nonexistent property it will create a blank one.

```
$allHeaders = $arrayOfObjects | % { Get-Member -inputobject $_ -membertype noteproperty | Select -expand Name } | Select -unique
$arrayOfObjects | Select $allHeaders
```

Granted you are looping through ever object to get the headers, so for a very large amount of objects it may take awhile.

Comment: This might work. I'll give it a go today and see if its plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a solution. I'm very tired now so hopefully it makes sense. Basically I'm calculating the largest amount of NIC and IP note properties, creating a place holder object that has those amounts of properties, adding it as the first item in a CSV, and then removing it from the CSV.

```
# Create example objects
$o1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
  ServerName="Mordor"
  IP1="10.0.0.1"
  IP2="10.0.0.2"
  NIC1="VMXNET"
  NIC2="Broadcom"
}

$o2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
  ServerName="Rivendell"
  IP1="10.1.1.1"
  IP2="10.1.1.2"
  IP3="10.1.1.3"
  IP4="10.1.1.4"
  NIC1="VMXNET"
}

# Add to an array
$servers = @($o1, $o2)

# Calculate how many IP and NIC properties there are
$IPColSize = ($servers | Select IP* | %{($_ | gm -MemberType NoteProperty).Count} | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]
$NICColSize = ($servers | Select NIC* | %{($_ | gm -MemberType NoteProperty).Count} | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]

# Build a place holder object that will contain enough properties to cover all of the objects in the array.
$cmd = '$placeholder = "" | Select ServerName, {0}, {1}' -f (@(1..$IPColSize | %{"IP$_"}) -join ", "), (@(1..$NICColSize | %{"NIC$_"}) -join ", ")
Invoke-Expression $cmd

# Convert to CSV and remove the placeholder
$csv = $placeholder,$servers | %{$_ | Select *} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$csv | Select -First 1 -Last ($csv.Count-2) | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv Solution.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yup, this is a good way when your number of properties is known. Sadly, it isn't really scalable and not something easy to deploy and use in multiple scripts. Ideally I was looking for some magical method that wouldn't require a count or calculations based on properties.